# How do I count the number of flowers (yellow) from the image in python

Tags: python, opencv

[image]I'm a newbie in python . I have tried to extract the flower (maybe not too accurate) but I need to : (1). be able count how many features has been extracted. (2) Other objects in the image that appears yellowish but not the object I wanted. Thanks for helping

Below is my code at the moment

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("female29.jpg")
image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

yellow = (204, 204, 0)
light_yellow = (255, 255, 204)

mask = cv2.inRange(image, yellow, light_yellow)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
cv2.imshow("image", result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: You would need to attach your image in order for this code to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no easy way to count the number of flowers present solely using opencv as what the above code does is only highlight or apply a mask to parts of image with the pixel values in the range you supplied.

```
yellow = (204, 204, 0)
light_yellow = (255, 255, 204)
```

you can try and change different values for your ranges to more accurately mask the flower
probably use an online [HSV color picker](https://pinetools.com/image-color-picker) to adjust the values (keep in mind you will have to scale the values from 0-100 to 0-255).

You can only try adjusting these values in order to prevent other Other objects in the image that appears yellowish but at the end of the day you're just applying a color filter, so everything that is yellow will show up and there is no way to stop that unless you use higher methods like Machine Learning to recognize flowers